# Run bash command in curl statement

Tags: python, bash, curl, slack

I am trying to execute a bash command as part of my curl statement. The bash command is suppose to execute a python file that displays some message. How can i go about achieving this? Here is my attempt, but does not work and displays a string of the command instead of actually executing the bash command:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#pxc-wsrep-test", "username": "webhookbot", "text": python test2.py, "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/F065ZJS3N/B4JT9K2TM/5KWZRYFIGhLL0MimiHAW6Gbz
```

Below is my python script, test2.py, that i want to execute:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = 'mysql -uroot -psecret -e"show status like \'wsrep_local_state_comment\'\G"'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

So i tried running curl inside the python script as demonstrated below:
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import requests

```
paylod={"text": 'mysql -uroot -psecret -e"show status like \'wsrep_local_state_comment\'\G"'}
r = request.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', data=payload)
print(r.test)
{
    "form": {
        "test": 'mysql -uroot -psecret -e"show status like \'wsrep_local_state_comment\'\G"'
     },
}
```

But i get the following error, even after installing pip and request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    r = request.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', data=payload)
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Comment: I think you have that backwards. How about including the curl statement inside of a bash script?

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example? Cos the with the curl, i just want to post a message which is a result of executing my bash command.

Comment: You can probably just run the curl command from Python. Just pick the glue you want to use: Bash or Python. curl is not a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to complicate things too much here. If we have access to the python script which is there in the sample we can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html) to do the job in python.

it can be as simple as using a post method with a data dictionary as mentioned [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Editing the response based on our last comment conversation

```
import requests # make sure we have requests installed or else use urllib
payload={"text": 'mysql -uroot -psecret -e"show status like \'wsrep_local_state_comment\'\G"'}
r = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: So i tried with the changed posted above using your recommendation, but seems not to be working.

Comment: Have you got requests installed ? Use pip to install requests or use  builtin urllib mofules. Requests is a module you need to import requests.

Answer (score -1):

You can use backticks or $command to run another command

For example

```
echo hi`echo bye`
```

OR

```
echo hi$(echo bye)
```